# Как сделать прозрачную маску?

Tags: html, css

Как сделать этот треугольник средствами css? Пробовал через clip и через border, но как-то всё тщетно

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Это делается с помощью псевдоэлементов, задавая определённый размер `border`'у:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.wrapper {
  margin: 1rem;
  position: relative;
}

.wrapper img {
  width: 100%;
}

.wrapper::before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  border-top: 250px solid;
  border-left: 250px solid;
  border-color: transparent rgba(255, 255, 0, 0.5);
}

.wrapper::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  border: none;
  border-bottom: 250px solid;
  border-right: 250px solid;
  border-color: transparent rgba(255, 0, 255, 0.5);
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/250x250">
</div>
```

Вариант на `SVG` (Adaptive):

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 500 500">
  <g>
    <image xlink:href="https://via.placeholder.com/200x200"/>
    <polygon points="0, 0 0, 200 200,200" fill="rgba(255, 0, 255, 0.5)"/>
    <polygon points="200, 0 200, 200 0,0" fill="rgba(255, 255, 0, 0.5)"/>
  </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: спасибо большое, вроде и сам так делал, но видимо где-то накосячил

Comment: @WVFFLIFE, был рад помочь:)

Comment: а как на счет адаптивности?

Comment: @WVFFLIFE, мне кажется с адаптивностью не выйдет, можно на `SVG` попробовать ещё, там с адаптивностью 100% будет

Comment: @WVFFLIFE, добавил второй вариант на `SVG`